# How can I remove the empty space from the Data table?

Tags: flutter, datatable, singlechildscrollview

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UryOQ.png)

I used SingleChildScrollView to make it scrollable but if the device size is big, there are empty spaces on the side.
[SingleChildScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cINUz.png)
How can I remove this that the content will stretch inside?

If I remove the SingleChildScrollView it will stretch and fit well, but if the screen is small it will not be scrollable and it overflows the table.
[Without scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbyB4.png)

I even tried using the fitted box, it stretches but it will be too big if the content of the table is just a few.
[FittedBox 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LpTf.png)
[FittedBox 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNkBd.png)

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: DataTable(),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Is this issue fixed? I am also faced this issue. Or any alternate solution please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Open DataTable (data_table.dart) class and search for _horizontalMargin,
Make it 0.0.
_horizontalMargin=0.0

Comment: this did not work. it removed the margin on the left but the big space on the right is still there because of the singlescrollview shrinkwrap, how can I expand it out?